# Adding a foreign key to a table

Tags: mysql, sql, god

I haven't practised SQL in a while and I forgot how to add a foreign key to my table

```
    mysql> alter table students 
add foreign key fk_unit(unitid) 
references unit(unitid) 
on delete no action 
on update cascade;
    ERROR 1072 (42000): Key column 'unitid' doesn't exist in table
```

I'm wondering why this is the case? My unit table has a primary key called unitid, why does this keep happening?

Comment: you have same name of column unitid in students table check it. I think it's different that's why giving error.

Comment: Your unit table has a column unitid but may be your student table doesn't have a column name unitid. That's what the error is implying.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one it should work....

```
ALTER TABLE students 
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_UnitId FOREIGN KEY (unitid)
    REFERENCES  unit(unitid);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
ALTER TABLE Students
ADD FOREIGN KEY (unitid)
REFERENCES unit(unitid)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query is correct. Looks like field 'unitid' is missing from 'students' table or it has a different name.